# Output figures to specific folder in Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I use gnuplot in Linux to plot residuals. I have all the input files named as **(in1, in2, ...)** in the **Folder1**, and I want to save all the output figures named as **(in1.png, in2.png, ...)** to **Folder2**.

This is my code:

```
# reaed inputs
FILES = system("ls ./Folder1/in*")

# create output folder
system "mkdir Folder2"
myOutput(s) = sprintf("%s.png",s)

# loop
do for [FILE in FILES] {
    set output myOutput(FILE) 
    plot "< awk '/for p/ {print $8}' ".FILE with lines
}
```

I try to modify the command `set output myOutput(FILE)`, like `set output './Folder2/myOutput(FILE)'`, but then the output files would named as **myOutput(FILE)**. I also try `'./Folder2'.myOutput(FILE)` but it generate the error `cannot open file; output not changed`.

Could anyone help me to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Aren't you missing a `/` on your second attempt? Have you tried: `'./Folder2/'.myOutput(FILE)`?

Comment: For debugging, I suggest you temporarily change the `set output ...` command inside the loop to `print ...` so that you can check what is going on. Like theozh I also suspect there is a typo somewhere.

Comment: @theozh Hi, thanks for suggestion. I tried but still error "system error: No such file or directory".

Comment: @Eldrad Hi, thanks for suggestion! By using the print function, I find the problem is the path of FILE. My FILE is a string `./Folder1/in1`, so the question transfers to extract the last column of string, i.e. 1. Do you know how to achieve this goal?

Comment: @WUYing You are using bash already, so I would use `awk`, `sed`, `grep` or whatever you like. It seems your question is becoming more and more unrelated to gnuplot…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the assumption that you are using Linux, you can use the command `basename` to extract only the last “in1" from the pathname ". /Folder1/in1".

```
% basename ./Folder1/in1
in1
```

If you permit to use this command, your code can be modified as follows.

```
# reaed inputs
FILES = system("ls ./Folder1/in*")

# create output folder
system "mkdir -p Folder2"
myOutput(s) = sprintf("./Folder2/%s.png",s)

# loop
do for [FILE in FILES] {
    BASENAME = system("basename ".FILE)
    set output myOutput(BASENAME) 
    plot "< awk '/for p/ {print $8}' ".FILE with lines
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Eldrad noted in the comments, there are certainly a variety of tools which you could use to solve your problem.

However, you can nevertheless do it in a platform independent (but pretty  cumbersome) way with gnuplot. You need to split your filename from the full pathname. Maybe there are even simpler ways with gnuplot that I am currently not aware of. Check the example below.

**Code:**

```
### create new output path+filename
reset session

# FILES = system("ls ./Folder1/in*")    # system command for Linux
# example result
FILES = "'./Folder1/in1' './Folder1/in2' './Folder1/in3' './Folder1/in4'"

# return position of the last occurrence of a character. If not found: length+1
PosLastChar(s,c) = (_a=strlen(s)+1, sum [_i=1:strlen(s)] (s[_i:_i] eq c ? _a=_i : _a), _a )

# create new filename
NewFile(p,s) = sprintf("%s/%s.png",p, s[PosLastChar(s,'/')+1:strlen(s)])

do for [FILE in FILES] {
    print NewFile('./Folder2',FILE)
}
### end of code
```

**Result:**

```
./Folder2/in1.png
./Folder2/in2.png
./Folder2/in3.png
./Folder2/in4.png
```

**Addition:**

Just for the records, there is a nicer and shorter way to split the filename from the path in gnuplot. You need to integrate the example below into the generation of your new filepath.
It uses a recursive function, therefore, it is limited to about 250 subdirectories, which however, should be enough for most cases.
For Linux use `/` and for Windows use  `\` as path splitter.

**Code:**

```
### split filename from full path
reset session

SplitFileName(s) = (_idx=strstrt(s,'/')) ? SplitFileName(s[_idx+1:]) : s

FILES = "'./Folder1/File1.dat' 'C:/MainFolder/Subfolder1/File2.txt' '../Sub1/Sub2/Sub3/File3.log' 'File4.exe'"

do for [FILE in FILES] {
    print SplitFileName(FILE)
}
### end of code
```

**Result:**

```
File1.dat
File2.txt
File3.log
File4.exe
```